# KENDO AJAX GRID HTMLHelper Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

Hi i am using KEndo Ajax Grid in my MVC project. I am using a htmlhlper in my grid to simply go into the new page but i am getting the error "mvc.HTMLHelper does not contain a definition for ActionLink and the best extension method overload"

My Code

```
     <%: Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoGridAjaxEditing2.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerID).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerName).Template(c => @Html.ActionLink(c.CustomerID, "ViewDetails", new { id = c.CustomerID }));
              columns.Bound(product => product.CustomerLastName).Width(250);
              columns.Bound(product => product.Customerage).Width(250);
              columns.Command(commands =>
              {
                  commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
                  commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items
              }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
          })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) // The "create" command adds new data items
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) // Use inline editing mode
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              dataSource.Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(product => product.CustomerID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                    model.Field(product => product.CustomerID).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable
                })
                .Create(create => create.Action("Products_Create", "Home")) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
                .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))  // Action invoked when the grid needs data
                .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Home"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Products_Destroy", "Home")) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
          )
          .Pageable()
%>
```

Help needed thanks

Comment: can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

How to use action links is covered [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-action-links?).

Comment: thanks mate please can you tell me one more thing i am new in asp.net mvc so that is why i am struggling i want to add dropbox and checkbox in my grid i have seen the demo source code as well from here http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html but in EditingController.cs i am not to able to find this public ActionResult Editing_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(SessionProductRepository.All().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

Comment: SessionProductRepository *?? is there source code available for kendo demo

Comment: Yes if you have installed the MVC extensions with the msi installer you should have the MVC demos under ProgramFIles/Telerik/Kendo...